# Connect a SQLite Database in Swift

Tags: swift, sqlite

I have a problem when I try to create the path to my database in my iOS Application. I am a beginner in SQLite so I prefer ask here to have an answer.

I use this gitHub source of SQLite 3 for make and use a database in Swift, a GitHub source: https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift and I have an error which appears: "Missing argument label 'coder:' in call".

Then I fix this error by putting coder: before my path and another error appears: "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument 'NSCoder'.

```
static let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( .documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
static let db = try Connection(coder: "\(path)/data.sqlite3")
```

Comment: `try Connection("\(path)/data.sqlite3")` as in your initial screenshot should compile. Please post a small self-contained example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @MartinR I was about to try that, because it should've worked, but I still wonder why he got the error in the first place. Is it because of Swift compiler issues?

Comment: The problem is here before the compilation

Comment: what do you mean 'before compilation'? there is only compile time and then after it comes runtime. Nothing is before compile time. Did you even attempt to build or run your code? Sometimes the compiler doesn't work correctly and simply building make the error go away.

Comment: I meant that I can't compile my code because there is an error before on this line and I don't know how to fix this error. Sorry for being unprecise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solve with delete and put sqlite again.

Thanks for the help.